# No Web Page publishing options for ClickOnce in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, clickonce

I have an outlook ad-in for which I want to create a ClickOnce install from a web page.

The steps are described here:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ws69w0k3(v=vs.120).aspx
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k5befhe3(v=vs.120).aspx

I cannot find the "Deployment" option described in step 4 in the first link above (using Visual Studio 2013):

[image]

Comment: if you publish - what files are created in the folder?

Comment: In the publish folder the following appear: Application Folder, Outlook_MyApp_Plugin.vsto and setup.exe. In the Application Folder are the various release version folders, and in each of those the specific versions .vsto, .deploy, .config.deploy and resource files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I haven't found an explicit explanation for the lack of ClickOnce Deployment options for my project, but I have discovered the following:

When creating a WPF or WinForms project the Deployment options I am looking for are present, so this is not a VS 2013 issue.

[image]

The only other thing I can guess is that the web deployment options are limited because the project is an Outlook Add In.

The steps for using ClickOnce with Office Solutions are described here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772100(v=vs.120).aspx

So I ended up adding the manifest file (.vsto) as an IIS MIME type and using the link http://theserver/myapp/outlook2013/Outlook_Jazz.vsto to distribute and update the application.

On a side note, I found these very important considerations if you intending to make use of ClickOnce:

http://www.codemag.com/article/0902031